# The relationship between drools ruleflow and JBPM?

Tags: drools, jbpm

1. I am confusing of the relationship between drools ruleflow and JBPM，and does it necessary to import JBPM package "jbpm-flow" and "jbpm-flow-builder" while use ruleflow?
2. I have read Drools Documentation, and notice that there are some examples such as "Number Guess", it contains files called "NumberGuess.drl" and "NumberGuess.rf". I don't know how drools works with ".rf" file, is there any documents or blog about it?  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time (2008 maybe?), there were 2 different projects:

- Drools: rule engine
- JBPM: flow engine

These 2 projects were completely independent one from the other. At some point, Drools introduced a way to execute flow-like logic inside it's engine (no completely true though). At that point, JBoss was working in 2 rule engines in parallel: JBPM and Drools Flow.

At some point in 2008/9, most of the JBPM team leaves JBoss and move to Activiti. JBoss then decided to rebrand Drools Flow as JBPM 5 and to deprecate the codebase from JBPM 4.

`.rf` files were the files used by the old Drools Flow engine. Nowadays, JBPM executes a different type of files: `.bpmn`.

If you just want to execute rules in Drools (5 or greater), then you don't need to include any JBPM dependency at all.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you very much!  What I gonna to do is something like graphical Rule Flow Editor in eclipse, but define rule-flow in web interface. I try to use JSON as data-interchange format between web interface and server, and then convert it to `.rf` file. Is there any better solution?  Thanks again!